# Front panel audio jacks (both speaker and microphone) not functional in linux while perfectly functional under windows

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, microphone, headphones

**Summary**

I am working on a server with the following hardware specs: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=b1e3f41ed1. This server's audio channels associated with the front panel audio jacks are not properly serviced by Linux. (However, these audio channels are perfectly functional on Windows 10: jacks being plugged into the sockets are detected, and all speakers/mike work perfectly in that OS.)

**Details**

I installed multiple operating systems with different kernels, including the following:
Ubuntu 22.04, Xubuntu 20.04, 22.04, Fedora 3.7 (Workstation), OpenSUSE (TumbleWeed), Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4. All of them manifest the same problem.

Alsamixer shows the following:

[image]

And when I select the card the HD-Audio Generic (5), it says "This sound device does not have any controls":

[image]

And if I select the USB Audio (1), alsamixer crashes saying "cannot load mixer controls: Broken pipe":

[image]

Reinstalling/restarting the pavucontrol does not help.

I installed Audacity on Linux and found out that the hardware servicing these input/output jacks is actually visible to this software (as hw:1,2 and hw:1,1) as follows:

[image]

I've gone through all the suggestions on stackexchange (and elsewhere) I could find and finally found this guide -- http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm. Going through the decision chart in the guide led me to finally ask my question here.

One more thing that can be noted is that Windows 10 detects my sound device as Realtek (Supermicro, the motherboard manufacturer provided a driver for windows "Realtek: RtkUWP_1.20.238.0"), while Linux detects it as "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller" and uses Intel driver for it, (as specified here: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1022-1487-1022-d102).

Please let me know how to make this audio device function on Linux.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.